# Loadrunner Analysis threw an error and i have no idea what could have caused these many errors

Tags: testing, performance-testing, loadrunner

We recently ran a PT and while loading the result of that test in Analysis i got a popup telling me that there was an error, the error trace is below. I am not sure what could have caused these many errors or what they even mean. I check the Analysis report and it had all the necessary information.

One of the experts told me that the errors were there because i was capturing snaphots of error during the test run but i am not convienced, how can taking snaphots generate so many errors!!

Could one of the loadrunner experts here help me understand what these errors mean and what could have caused them?

Log Trace is available at: https://docs.google.com/document/d/16gfaAXpGcKC8f6wfKU_dVjM-IqfbzWgdM6VvVYvo68Q/edit

Answer (score 1):

Related to the questions on scope of the error above: From your error log....

```
75004 Transaction : <OpenWebPage_Login_31>
InstanceID: 4294967299 
VUser info:
+Host:HostMachine_IP, 
+Group:scriptname.1, 
+Script:scriptname.1, 
+ID:1. 
End Time: 1357937049.69605 
Transaction end time is less than the scenario start time
```

I have cleaned up a single line in your log for clarity purposes.   Note that the line includes a couple of items which have been scrubbed, such as "HostMachine_IP."   You may also examine the hosting for group, "scriptname.1" to find out which load generator host this is applied to.

As you have indicated that you have multiple load generators involved, examine carefully the scope of the errors in the error log.   Are they all tied to one particular hostname?  If you have more than one group on the same host then are both groups impacted by this error (error follows host and not group).   If the error is tied to a script and to a group, then does the same error occur with the same script in another group on another load generator, such a single user running as a control set on a different load generator?

Break The errors apart.   Examine the errors critically.   All Hosts mean one thing:  One host another.   A instances of a script across multiple load generators mean one thing:  Instances on a single load generator another.  All scripts on one load generator imply one thing, especially when the instances on a second/third load generator do not fail.

Comment: I did track it down to just one load generators, unfortunately i did not get an opportunity to dig on this any further. In the end the errors went away when i disabled error snapshots and now i am off working for another client.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of your load generators are at the same major.minor(patch) release level as your controller.

Comment: The Load Generators are at the same patch level as the controller. Also there are other tests whose result opened up fine in the Analysis tool.

Comment: Scope?   Does this error of end time earlier than test start time immpact particular groups, user types or load generators?   This should be telling (I am assuming multiple groups and multiple load generators)

Comment: i am not sure how to find that out and yes we do have multiple load generators.